# recursive procedure working in localhost not in server

Tags: mysql, recursion, stored-procedures, mlm

I am having two different tables users and invoice_order

users table -

```
+-------+-------+-----------+
| pid   | fname |    iid    |                
+=======+=======+===========+
| sk001 | aa    | null      |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk002 | ss    | ssk001    |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk003 | dd    | sk001     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk004 | ff    | sk002     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk005 | gg    | sk002     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk006 | hh    | sk005     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk007 | jj    | sk006     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk008 | kk    | sk006     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk009 | ll    | sk004     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk010 | mm    | sk005     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
      Here `pid` is personal id of the user and `iid` is the parent_id of the users
```

invoice_order table -

```
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| pid   | fname | iid       |order_to|
+=======+=======+===========+========+
| sk001 | aa    | null      | 100    |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk002 | ss    | ssk001    | 400    |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk002 | dd    | sk001     | 225    |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk004 | ff    | sk002     | 50     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk005 | gg    | sk002     | 59     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk006 | hh    | sk005     | 77     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk007 | jj    | sk006     | 89     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk004 | ff    | sk002     | 87     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk009 | ll    | sk004     | 45     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk010 | mm    | sk005     | 56     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
```

And I am using a procedure `team_total_test` to calculate the team total of a individual user using a recursive query in the procedure

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `team_total_test`(IN `userid` VARCHAR(200))
        NO SQL
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE tt_3 (pid VARCHAR(100),iid VARCHAR(100),total INT(250));
    INSERT INTO tt_3  SELECT  pid,
            iid,0
    from    (SELECT pid,iid from users
             order by pid, iid) users,
            (SELECT @pv := userid) initialisation
    where   find_in_set(iid, @pv) > 0
    and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', pid)) order by iid ASC;
       UPDATE tt_3 
       SET total=(SELECT (SUM(order_total_before_tax))/2 FROM invoice_order WHERE tt_3.pid=invoice_order.pid 
         AND MONTH(order_date)=MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(order_date)=YEAR(NOW()) );
        SELECT  sum(total) as total_pv
    from    tt_3 ;
       SELECT COUNT(pid) as counting FROM tt_3;
       DROP TABLE tt_3 ;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

The Problem is I am getting correct output in localhost and not in server
output from localhost  is
[image: output from localhost]
output in server is
[image: output in server]

Comment: 'team total of a individual user ' - I don't know what this means. Is it the total for all the members of a team for which a user is also a member, and a users can be a member of multiple teams?

Comment: team total is the total of the orders created by the users under a parent @P.Salmon

Comment: Always nice to have code and data that match - I suppose pid in SELECT pid,iid from users is id in the sample provided? and where is order_total_before_tax and what id do you pass to the SP to get the results you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities

1. The server clock is different from your local clock (so the month may be --- one is October and one is November) -- because I notice that your SQL contains the MONTH(NOW()) parameter.
2. You local environment 's case-sensitivity may be different from the server case-sensitivity (for example, a windows machine may treat CASE and case the same, but a linux one will for sure treat them as different)

Comment: Thank you @ken Lee I have gone checked the two possibilities ..but it struck somewhere..